# create virtual machine without iso file

Tags: virtualbox

I currently have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my computer. However, I downloaded it from the Microsoft store so I don't have an iso file. Is there a way to connect it to the virtual box without an iso file?

Comment: My experience is that WSL and VBox can not be installed on the same computer, you will need to remove WSL and Hyper-V before using VBox.

Answer (score 3):

When you say you "downloaded from the Microsoft store" I would assume you downloaded Ubuntu for WSL. This is entirely separate from Virtualbox.

The `.iso` file does not represent an actual installation of Ubuntu or a virtual machine, but an image of a disk that contains the installer. If you have something you would like to migrate, you'd be best off migrating to a virtual machine as you would with any other installation: copying the necessary files and reinstalling software. So, in effect, the answer to your question is "no". You may be able to migrate a Linux installation in WSL to a VM even without just copying the files through some tool, but if you just want to make a VM, which is what it appears you want to do, you should download the `.iso` and use that in Virtualbox.

Comment: An excellent and useful explanation!

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears up a lot of things for me!